# How to get url from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My code :

```
mStorageRef.child("image/pizza.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                        System.out.println(uri.toString() + "!!!!!!");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });
```

But it only prints:

> https://console.firebase.google.com/u/1/project/e-commerce-ddd1c/database/e-commerce-ddd1c/data

I don't understand how to get this url:
[image]

Comment: what are you getting from uri.toString()?

Comment: I am getting firebase storage url of image

Comment: yes that is what you are supposed to get. The url in the image you added that is what you will get. Also we cannot access your database, from the link that you provided

Comment: @ИльяФедосеев Is this not what you want?

Comment: try mStorageRef.child("image/pizza.jpg").getDownloadUrl().getResult();

Comment: @IDroid it doesn't work